# How to create a WPF Window that spreads across all the monitors

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a setup where multiple monitors of different resolutions are connected vertically, I want to create a single WPF Window that will get maximized on all the screens.

I tried the below solution and did not work and created output like below.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    this.Topmost = true;

    this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
    this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;1
    Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    this.Show();
}

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle totalBounds = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens
        .Select(screen => screen.Bounds)
        .Aggregate(Rectangle.Union);

    
    this.Left = totalBounds.Left;
    this.Top = totalBounds.Top;
    this.Width = totalBounds.Width;
    this.Height = totalBounds.Height;            

    var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).EnsureHandle();
    WindowsServices.SetWindowPos(hwnd, WindowsServices.HWND_TOPMOST, (int)this.Left, (int)this.Top, (int)this.Width, (int)this.Height, WindowsServices.SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

My screen setup is like

[image]

I have tried this [code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1165544/WPF-Windows-on-Two-Screens), and this guy is creating new windows for each of the screens, which I don't want.

Comment: I think better to create new window for each monitor but share ViewModel. Otherwise it needs some kind of rendering hacking.

Comment: I'm doubtful if this is possible, and it seem likely to result in all kinds of issues. Why specifically do you not want one window per screen?

Comment: @jonasH, My other windows all have single instances only, so I wanted to find a solution using a single window instance.

Comment: That make very little sense to me.  Having multiple instances of windows should be trivial, and is very common. Making a single window work well across multiple different resolution screen, with possibly arbitrary positioning, seem extraordinary difficult, if at all possible.